# Measuring HTML equivalence?

Tags: java, html, libraries

I'm wondering if anyone knows of a good library for Java to use to measure HTML equivalence?

For example `<td class="one two three" name="goat">` would be equivalent to `<td name="goat" class="three two one">`.  I would like to compare entire many-lined strings of html in this manner using Java.

Any suggestions?

UPDATE:

so I tried the use of XmlUnit's Diff.similar() and found that I was getting that these two were similar:

`<html three="3" two="2" one="1"></html>` and `<html one="one" two="two"></html>`

This is undesired behavior...  Are there any other options?

Comment: Sounds like you want to parse it as XML, then compare the doc tree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a html parser like [NekoHTML](http://nekohtml.sourceforge.net/) or [JTidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/), and then use the [Diff](http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/api/org/custommonkey/xmlunit/Diff.html) class of [XMLUnit](http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/) to compare the two XML documents.

Comment: Diff().similar() sounds like what I'm looking for.  Thanks.

Comment: so I tried the use of .similar() and found that I was getting that these two were similar:
<html three="c" two="b" one="a"></html> and <html one="a" two="b" ></html> which is not the desired behavior...

Comment: I just tried to compare the two documents you specified using Diff.similar and it returned false...How did you do it ?